# How to compile module

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I currently have one main applications where parts of which can be "live-patched". Eg. some functions with predefined name and signature can be updated during runtime. Currently, the repatching is performed by this two steps:

- use std::process::Command to call rustc to compile a cdylib from the source. Each output file has a new name in order to make sure that dlopen does not use the cached old file
- use libloading to load and run the newly patched function

This is obviously not ideal for a couple of reasons. My question would be if there is a better way to achieve this? Eg do the compilation from within rust.

Additional info:

- The patch files do not require any external crates
- The patch files need to be aware of some common lib modules, which do not get live patched

Comment: How is the live-patching triggered? In particular, is it triggered by the program itself or by some other program?

Comment: You're patching the assembly, not the source code, correct?

Comment: @SolomonUcko. It is triggered by the program itself.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm not sure I understand the question, would you mind clarifying it for me? I currently compile (from a source file) a dynamically linked library and then load it via dlopen (abstracted by libloading).

Comment: I recommend taking a look at https://github.com/google/evcxr/blob/main/evcxr/README.md.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this; what problems are you experiencing with your current approach?

Comment: @magu_ My mistake. I thought there are two _options_, but you said two _steps_.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time all of the options that can be generated?

Comment: You may want to patch the machine code rather than the Rust code. But this is much more complicated.